# Syncing a dynamic set of schemata using SymmetricDS

Tags: symmetricds

I am working on a desktop application that uses a local installation of MySQL to store data across multiple schemata. My goal is to use `SymmetricDS` to transfer those schemata to an `Oracle` database on a different machine.

So far I managed to set up a slave node residing on the desktop computer and a master node residing on some server. Using a `.properties` file in the engine directory, I also successfully transfer data from a single schema and table to the Oracle DB.

The problem I am now facing is that my application will create and possibly delete schemata on the fly.

Does that mean I will have to maintain a .properties file for each schema and somehow implement a wrapper for the `symadmin` command to register the corresponding engines?

Or is there maybe a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should able to adjust configuration on the fly.  The sym_trigger table has a reference to schema for each table.  If the database user SymmetricDS uses has access to newly created schemas (database) then SymmetricDS should be able to create new triggers dynamically that are in new databases.  No restart needed.